# How can I assign long expressions inside SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I not repeat the usage of `avg(examinee_grade_science + ...)`?

As you can see I repeated it under the `CASE` expression. Can I assign it to a variable and use it in the `CASE` expression?

I tried using `SET (set @ave_grade = examine_grade...)` but it's not working.
Is there anyway it could be possible?

```
select  
    examinee_grade_science as "Science Grade", 
    examinee_grade_math as "Math Grade", 
    examinee_grade_literature as "Literature Grade",
    examinee_grade_science + examinee_grade_math +  examinee_grade_literature as "TOTAL",
    avg(examinee_grade_science + examinee_grade_math + examinee_grade_literature) as "AVERAGE",  
    case when avg(examinee_grade_science + examinee_grade_math + examinee_grade_literature) < 93 
        then 'PASSED' 
        else 'FAILED' 
    end as "REMARKS"
from examinee
```

Comment: Why it's not working? What is the error or incorrect value?

Comment: just want to simplify it so it doesn't appear long

Answer (score 3):

Use a subquery to calculate average and then use the alias assigned to average calculkated in outer query to check for Pass/Fail

```
SELECT *,
 case when AVERAGE < 93 
                    then 'PASSED' 
                    else 'FAILED' 
              end as "REMARKS"
FROM
(
    select  
                  examinee_grade_science as "Science Grade", 
                  examinee_grade_math as "Math Grade", 
                  examinee_grade_literature as "Literature Grade",
                  examinee_grade_science + examinee_grade_math +  examinee_grade_literature as "TOTAL",
                  avg(examinee_grade_science + examinee_grade_math + examinee_grade_literature) as "AVERAGE"



    from examinee
) t
```

Comment: how do i mark this as answered? sorry still new here

Comment: just want to ask? What is that 't' for at the end of the code?

Comment: this is compulsory alias provided to resultset returned by inner subquery

Comment: thanks a lot! okay i'm gonna set this as answered tho i'm still looking for that tick mark lol God bless you mah friend! :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `CROSS APPLY` to create an alias for an expression:

```
select
    examinee_grade_science as "Science Grade", 
    examinee_grade_math as "Math Grade", 
    examinee_grade_literature as "Literature Grade",
    grade_sum as "TOTAL",
    avg(grade_sum) as "AVERAGE",
    case when avg(grade_sum) < 93 
        then 'PASSED' 
        else 'FAILED' 
    end as "REMARKS"
from
    examinee
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT 
            examinee_grade_science + examinee_grade_math + examinee_grade_literature AS grade_sum
    ) AS A
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Average alias in case? In Teradata, alias can be used in case statement. Please check if it is possbiel in SQL server or not?

```
select  
              examinee_grade_science as "Science Grade", 
              examinee_grade_math as "Math Grade", 
              examinee_grade_literature as "Literature Grade",
              examinee_grade_science + examinee_grade_math +  examinee_grade_literature as "TOTAL",
              avg(examinee_grade_science + examinee_grade_math + examinee_grade_literature) as "AVERAGE",


              case when AVERAGE < 93 
                    then 'PASSED' 
                    else 'FAILED' 
              end as "REMARKS"


from examinee
```

Comment: I can not see group by too in your query. hope it is just typo from your side.

Comment: I don't think your average is going to do what you think it does, don't you want to add them up and divide by 3?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query(Not tested)

```
;with cte as (
select  
              examinee_grade_science as "Science Grade", 
              examinee_grade_math as "Math Grade", 
              examinee_grade_literature as "Literature Grade",
              examinee_grade_science + examinee_grade_math +  examinee_grade_literature as "TOTAL"
from examinee)
select *,avg(Total) as "Total",case when avg(Total)<93 then 'PASSED' else 'FAILED' end as "REMARKS" from cte
```